# Generate percentage for each group based on column values using Python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below. I would like to group them based on subject_id, hadm_id and icustay_id. Once I group it, I would like to extract subjects that has more than 60% pc of 1's in 'val_bw_80_110' column. From the below example , we can see that subject_id = 38 satisfies this condition (all values for val_bw_80_110 = 1, which means 100%) and I would like to extract the group which belongs to subject_id = 38. If there had been only two 1's then the percentage would have been 66.666 etc

[image]

I have already tried using groupby but unable to proceed further as I am not sure how to get the percentage of values in a column

```
data = [[38,10,110,1,0,0], [38,10,110,1,0,0],[38,10,110,1,0,0], 
[28,11,120,1,0,0],[28,11,120,0,1,0],[28,11,120,0,0,1],
   [48,13,130,1,0,0],[48,13,130,0,1,0],[48,13,130,0,0,1]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['subject_id','hadm_id','icustay_id',
'val_bw_80_110','val_lt_80','val_gt_110'])
new_df = df.groupby(['subject_id','hadm_id','icustay_id'])
```

My expected result is just a dataframe which contains all the subjects that satisfy the condition of 60% of 1's in val_bw_80_110. The output dataframe should have all the records (along with columns) for subject_id = 38

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I think how looks final DataFrame.

Comment: The output dataframe would contain all the records with subject_id = 38 because that was the only subject_id which exceeded the limit of 60% of 1's in val_bw_80_110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for get percentage of `1` values:

```
df1 = (df[df.groupby(['subject_id','hadm_id','icustay_id'])['val_bw_80_110']
            .transform('mean').ge(0.6)])
print (df1)
   subject_id  hadm_id  icustay_id  val_bw_80_110  val_lt_80  val_gt_110
0          38       10         110              1          0           0
1          38       10         110              1          0           0
2          38       10         110              1          0           0
```

If use `transform` get Series with same size like original DataFrame, so possible filtering:

```
print (df.groupby(['subject_id','hadm_id','icustay_id'])['val_bw_80_110']
            .transform('mean'))
0    1.000000
1    1.000000
2    1.000000
3    0.333333
4    0.333333
5    0.333333
6    0.333333
7    0.333333
8    0.333333
Name: val_bw_80_110, dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (df.groupby(['subject_id','hadm_id','icustay_id'])['val_bw_80_110']
            .transform('mean').ge(0.6))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: val_bw_80_110, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Just trying to understand both the solutions. Can you please let me know what's the use of transform('mean'), instead of directly using mean()

Comment: Can you help me with this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592014/merge-multiple-dataframes-using-multiindex-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean index of `subject_id`'s that meet your criteria, then use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter them.

```
s = df.groupby(['subject_id','hadm_id','icustay_id'])['val_bw_80_110'].mean().ge(0.6)

df.loc[df.subject_id.isin(s.index.levels[0][s])]
```

[output]

```
   subject_id  hadm_id  icustay_id  val_bw_80_110  val_lt_80  val_gt_110
0          38       10         110              1          0           0
1          38       10         110              1          0           0
2          38       10         110              1          0           0
```